# Loop in Rstudio

Tags: r, loops

I want to know how to make a loop in R.
I show a very simple example of a code below,

```
Test_A <- Test %>% mutate (A = 1)
Test_B <- Test %>% mutate (B = 1)
Test_C <- Test %>% mutate (C = 1)
Test_D <- Test %>% mutate (D = 1)
```

I want to make a loop for this code and make it more simple because this code is too repetitive.
Do anyone have suggestion for me?

Comment: You'll likely get a recommendation or two that suggests the use of `assign`. I discourage this behavior, it typically *slows down* how you work on your project, and makes for inefficient code. Consider keeping it as a "list of frames", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272

Comment: In which case, `lapply(LETTERS[1:4], function(cn) { Test[[cn]] <- 1; Test; })`

Comment: Please take a tutorial to learn basics for how to program R. This is a very general and very basic question that would be explained by any tutorial. And the answer is probably that you don't want to use a loop, you want to use a vector operation. But there is no way to tell from your example what you are trying to do or why.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a sample data.frame like

```
set.seed(5)
vals <- LETTERS[1:5]
Test <- data.frame(Map(function(...) sample(0:1, 10, replace=T), vals))
```

Then it would be better to keep these different datasets in a list rather than have them as separate variables in your namespace. You could do

```
Outs <- Map(function(x) Test %>% mutate (!!x := 1), vals)
```

Then you can get at the data with `Outs[["A"]]`, `Outs[["B"]]`, etc...

Comment: I nearly posted the same thing. The double bang and `:=` operator might benefit from a little exposition here given the presumed level of the OP's familiarity with the language.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thank you for your kind comment. It is my bad that the sample code I shown here was not actually what I want to do. I really want to make a loop for different strings. I appreciate your help!